# disk space utilized files

Tags: linux

Linux command to find largely disk space utilized file.
I need to list all files in the order of size

Comment: Belongs to superuser.com.

Answer (score 2):

```
du -k | sort -rn | head -n 50
```

Where:

- The **`du`** utility displays the file system block usage for each file argument and for each directory in the file hierarchy rooted in each directory argument.  If no file is specified, the block usage of the hierarchy rooted in the current directory is displayed. `-k` will display block counts in 1024-byte (1-Kbyte) blocks.
- **`sort`** is self-explanatory. `-r` reverses the result of comparisons, placing the highest value atop the list. `-n` compares according to string numerical value.
- **`head`** only shows the top *`n`* rows. 50 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Always keep something like this tucked away in an alias somewhere:

```
find / -type f | xargs ls -s | sort -rn | awk '{size=$1/1024; printf("%dMb %s\n", size,$2);}' | head
```

Comment: expensive as ls is called on every individual file.  -printf instead of xargs resolves that.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

For the / device, and only for that device, this prints the 500 largest files with their size in megabytes. Omit the "head -n 500" and it'll print all files with sizes, sorted largest first.

```
find / -xdev -type f -printf "%s %h/%f\n" | sort -rn -k1 | head -n 500 | awk '{ print $1/1048576 "MB" " " $2}'
```